# stream data from datastax to gephi using gremlin

Tags: datastax, gremlin, gephi

I am using gremlin-console (v3.2.7) bundled with Datastax Enterprise. On start it automatically connects to a remote gremlin server. Next, I create an alias to access the right graph `:remote config alias g graph.g`. Then, I connect to gephi (v0.9.2) `:remote connect tinkerpop.gephi`. From this moment on, however, I cannot traverse graph `g` so that `:> g` logically fails with `java.lang.StackOverflowError` as well. These are the two connections:

```
gremlin> :remote list
==>0 - Gremlin Server - [localhost/127.0.0.1:8182]-[<uuid>]
==>*1 - Gephi - [workspace1]
```

My question is whether there is a way to stream data from one remote connection to another using the setup outlined above (Datastax -> gephi) and if so how? If not, is there a workaround?

**Note:** All connections are successful, local gephi streaming tested with `TinkerGraph.createModern()` works flawlessly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Gephi plugin requires a local `Graph` instance. When you connect the Gremlin Console using `:remote` you no longer have that (i.e. the `Graph` instance is on a server somewhere and you're sending via `:>` the request to the server to be processed over there).

DSE Graph, Neptune, CosmosDB and similar graphs that only offer a remote `Graph` instance, the only way that you can make the Gephi plugin work is by [taking a subgraph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#subgraph-step) and bringing that down to your Gremlin Console. Then, as you've found, TinkerGraph (i.e. the holder of the subgraph) will work just fine with the Gephi plugin.

Comment: Could you elaborate "Taking a subgraph and bringing that down to your Gremlin Console"? Do we have to save the remote subgraph into disk and then load it back into a local graph? Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the graph database you are connected to, you can simply return a TinkerGraph as the result of your `subgraph()` operation. TinkerGraph should be fully serializable with a Gryo connection. Depending on the size of that TinkerGraph that may or may not be acceptable. If the graph you are using does not directly support TinkerGraph serialization, you could write that TinkerGraph to a String and return the String. I guess you could also write the subgraph to the remote disk and potentially get it there - if you have access to do such things.